# jquery datepicker: beforeShowDay

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i like to change the clickable state of a date in a datepicker. Therefore i use beforeShowDay:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var dateTime = parseInt(date.getTime()/1000);
        if (isWeekend(date)){
            return [false,''];
        }
        var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
        var specialDates = getSpecialSet(y,m);
        for (i = 0; i < specialDates.length; i++) {
            if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,specialDates) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
                console.log('HL: '+(m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y);
                return [true,'highlight1','Almost sold out'];
            }
        }
        return [true,'normal']; // ordinary day
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var d = new Date(dateText);
        cal_gotoDate(d);
    }
});
```

I load my **specialDates** via the function `getSpecialSet(y,m)`. This function will be run for each date in the current month. Because my specialDates set is very big: There are specialDates for the next 20 years. I like to load the specialset by ajax only for the current month.

But i need a function that will get called after the month is changed to preload my specialDates via ajax.

But i didnt find any usefull function in the api.

Comment: since you are planning to use ajax it may not be possible, because by the time the ajax request is completed, `beforeShowDay` would have been called for that month

Answer (score 0):

Load all months data in advance using Ajax, but the code to associate the datepicker with #DataePicker in the call back function of the Ajax call.